# Bootstrap Datepicker - How to send value to URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I must admit I'm hopeless on Javascript, PHP is more in my comfort zone.

I'm trying to use Bootstrap Datepicker for a booking system. I'm trying to find a way that when you click on a date it will reload the page and send the date to the URL.

Something like: `http://example.com/test.php?date=2014-02-04`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:  Simplified code, pulls back the date but won't send to URL

```
<div>
         <form action="test.php" method="GET">
         <input type="text" placeholder="click to show datepicker"  id="startDate">
         </form>
         <script>
         $('#startDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function() {
         $(this).parent('form').submit();
         });
        </script>
        </div>




   <script type="text/javascript">
        // When the document is ready
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#startDate').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            });  

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Fix your link please; it doesn't work.

Comment: It's not supposed to work. OP is just showing an example of how he/she wants the date value to be passed on to a URL as part of the query string. Wasn't that obvious, since the url says `/test.php..`

Comment: What is the main problem? Is the form effectively being sent to the server with a blank date, or it doesn't send it after change the date?

Comment: set name attribute `<input id="startDate" name="startDate">`

Comment: Good spot. Just added the name attribute but still doesn't send :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just have it in a form with method set to GET, and then submit the form on date change:

```
<form action="test.php" method="GET">
    <input id="date" name="date">
</form>

<script>
   $('#date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function() {
         $(this).parent('form').submit();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I am. I think that is definitely along the right lines but won't reload the page with the date sent to the url.