# DatePicker: combine quarterly picker with submit functionality

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

How to combine a quarter datePicker

(see: [SO: how-to-change-bootstrap-datepicker-month-view-to-display-quarters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383750/how-to-change-bootstrap-datepicker-month-view-to-display-quarters)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mwk0d5L/1/ )

with a submit functionality?

(like: [SO: bootstrap-datepicker-how-to-send-value-to-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540558/bootstrap-datepicker-how-to-send-value-to-url)?)

I tried:

```
$('#example1').datepicker({
    format: "MM yyyy",
    minViewMode: 1,
    autoclose: true,
    language: "qtrs",
    forceParse: false
}).on("show", function (event) {

    $(".month").each(function (index, element) {
        if (index > 3) $(element).hide();
    });
}).on('changeDate', function () {
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
});
```

but it does not seem to work.

Here is the jsFiddle I have used:
http://jsfiddle.net/a1t465c7/

Comment: Hi, content inside changeDate event is executed. I think submit instruction couldn't be ok.       
Please, post html code too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a1t465c7/ added to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It should work.
Content inside changeDate event is executed.
Try this:

```
$('#example1').datepicker({
    format: "MM yyyy",
    minViewMode: 1,
    autoclose: true,
    language: "qtrs",
    forceParse: false
}).on("show", function (event) {

    $(".month").each(function (index, element) {
        if (index > 3) $(element).hide();
    });
}).on('changeDate', function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/76Lhvfy0/

May be a problem with the following instruction:

```
$(this).parent('form').submit();
```